# PHP loop - keep running function if the result is the same

Tags: php, loops

The function below generates random numbers. Is there a way to check whether the next number is not equal to the previous. And keep running the function while the current number matches some of the previous? Thanks!

```
$qde = //number of loops

for ($x = 1; $x <= $qde; $x++) {

        ger();

        }
```

Comment: Please show us your full code (+ function definition) and what you have tried to get your code working as you want!

Comment: "matches some of the previous" huh?

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. Example: The ger() = rand(1,100) . I want this function to loop 100 times and generates 100 different numbers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Funny how programming languages are close to our normal communication, you basically answered your own question and don't know about it...

> And keep running the function **while** the current number matches

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Update 1:

If you want to run the loop while the new number equals something there has already been, use in_array() php function

```
while(in_array($newNum,$array)){
    getNewNum();
}
```

I didn't do any development in php for long time, so not sure if the syntax is correct

Comment: While technically correct, try to add a code example as link-only answers may be subject to deletion for being low quality. Even a basic `while()` or  `do ... while()` syntax would make this a better answer.

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry, didn't have the time, considered downvoting the question at first because this is really not question from developer per se (I mean loop functions are almost the first things you learn...), but decided to be nice enough to share link... Will add example next time. Or just downvote :)

Comment: Thanks Tom. How can I keep running the same function if the current ger() is equal to some of the previous ger() in the loop?

Comment: @Tom I agree about the question, just be cautious posting answers without any code, you may get downvoted or have it removed :)

Comment: @TimLewis I get it, thanks :) As great as this community is (and really I mean it), im not really all big on my online reputation ;)